# Unable to import auto_arima from pmdarima Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, arima, pmdarima

I am trying to import the auto_arima function from pmdarima, but am encountering problems and was unable to do so.

The error message is as follow:

```
C:\Anaconda2\envs\ipykernel_py3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py in <module>
     19 import itertools
     20 
---> 21 import _multiprocessing
     22 
     23 from . import util

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _multiprocessing: The specified module could not be found.
```

I installed pmdarima using the command and was successful.

```
conda install -c saravji pmdarima
```

But I was unable to import the auto_arima function in the **pmdarima** package. I have tried upgrading numpy as it is mentioned in other posts, but that still didn't solve the problem.

Does anyone have any idea about this type of error? Thanks so much!

Comment: You need to install the same package via the anaconda navigator!

Comment: I couldn't find the package in the anaconda navigator. I have reinstalled anaconda and now I am good with it. Thanks for the comment though!

Comment: `conda install -c conda-forge statsmodels` will install a library called `statsmodel`. there is a function `from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem & and the reason is probably that you're using python 3.8 and `pmdarima` isn't installed there yet but u can try this while installing in jupyter

first cell: (installation)

```
! pip install pmdarima
import warnings 
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

The second Cell: (installing `auto_arima`)

```
from pmdarima import auto_arima
```